# How to loop through an object and modify the object data ES5

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have an object that I want to check if the value exists and modify each object based on the response.

Here is what I have:

```
object1.map(function(item) {
  return item.email;
})
var givenEmail = object1 //["hi@gmail.com","hi1@gmail.com","hi2@gmail.com"]
$.ajax({
  url: "/exists?email=" + givenEmail,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(emailData) {
    if (emailData.success == true) {
      object1.email + "-" + emailData.success // "hi@gmail.com - false"
    } else {
      object1.email + "-" + emailData.success // "hi@gmail.com - true"
    }
  }
});
```

My object should look like

```
["hi@gmail.com - false","hi1@gmail.com - false","hi2@gmail.com - false","hi3@gmail.com - false","hi4@gmail.com - false"]
```

Please also let me know if there are better ways to achieve this!

THANKS!

Comment: That's an array, not an object.

Comment: You need to assign the result of `object1.map()` to something. It returns a new array, it doesn't modify the original.

Comment: @Barmar yes, i need to check each value and concatenate the response to the value

Comment: `$.ajax` is asynchronous. You're going to need to use promises and `Promise.all()` to collect all the results in an array.

Comment: using &.ajax because this only happens during a certain event

Comment: What are you expecting `url: "/exists?email=" + givenEmail,` to do? `givenEmail` is an array of multiple emails. Do you want to send them all in a single AJAX request, or did you intend to loop over the array?